# When upgrading to Version 1.X, how to automatically switch the single quotation settings of existing data?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Previously I use Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB, and now I want to use Version 1.X. However there are still a lot of data in the older version, and the previous time series used '' single quotation marks in names and statements. Is there any good way to simply upgrade to 1.x without changing all these quotations one by one? When using "load" command, can IoTDB convert them automatically?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please